# Django filter-save QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've a django model:-

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Next, I query it:-

`obj = ModelA.objects.filter(flag=True)`

Now, I change the `flag` of first object.

```
obj1 = obj[0]
obj1.flag = False
obj1.save()
```

Now, when I get `obj[0]` again, it returns me the `2nd object` of the filtered query. **Why?**

Comment: How do you know it is the 2nd object? how are you evaluating it ? Probably - that is the issue, when you evaluate the queryset again, the second object becomes the first one which matches the criteria ?

Comment: I `print` it. The `id` of the object.

Comment: Take a look at [first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#first)

Comment: I know this. But I just wanna this weird behaviour of Django.

Comment: Because you are filtering by existing query, rerun your `obj = ModelA.objects.filter(flag=True)` and you will get rid of that element

Comment: `filtering by existing query`. Since I'm getting the object from the previous queryset itself, shouldnt it return the same object. ??

Comment: OR does it keep refreshing/firing the query?

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast the source code is the most accurate documentation, as always... But you can just look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that every time you run `obj[0]`, Django goes back to the database and runs the query. You can see the queries that are executed by using `django.db.connection`:

```
>>> from django.db import connection

>>> obj = ModelA.objects.filter(flag=True)
>>> print(connection.queries)
[]

>>> o = obj[0]
>>> print(connection.queries)
[{'time': '0.001', 'sql': 'SELECT "myapp_modela"."id", "myapp_modela"."flag" FROM "myapp_modela" WHERE "myapp_modela"."flag" = 1 LIMIT 1'}]

>>> o.flag = False
>>> o.save()
>>> print(connection.queries)
[{'time': '0.001', 'sql': 'SELECT "myapp_modela"."id", "myapp_modela"."flag" FROM "myapp_modela" WHERE "myapp_modela"."flag" = 1 LIMIT 1'},
 {'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'BEGIN'},
 {'time': '0.002', 'sql': 'UPDATE "myapp_modela" SET "flag" = 0 WHERE "myapp_modela"."id" = 1'}]

>>> o = obj[0]
>>> print(connection.queries)
[{'time': '0.001', 'sql': 'SELECT "myapp_modela"."id", "myapp_modela"."flag" FROM "myapp_modela" WHERE "myapp_modela"."flag" = 1 LIMIT 1'},
 {'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'BEGIN'},
 {'time': '0.002', 'sql': 'UPDATE "myapp_modela" SET "flag" = 0 WHERE "myapp_modela"."id" = 1'},
 {'time': '0.000', 'sql': 'SELECT "myapp_modela"."id", "myapp_modela"."flag" FROM "myapp_modela" WHERE "myapp_modela"."flag" = 1 LIMIT 1'}]
```

Comment: It only does this if it's `resultcache` is empty - which is the case if you don't iterate over the queryset first. Once you start iterating over the queryset, it will fill it's `resultcache` and then subsequent subscriptings will just return what's in the resultcache already.

Comment: Isnt it an overhead, querying the DB again. Isnt converting the queryset into the list a good idea, `list(ModelA.objects.filter(flag=True))`?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `Queryset.__getitem__()` (django/db/models/query.py), you'll find this (django 1.10):

```
295  qs = self._clone()
296  qs.query.set_limits(k, k + 1)
297  return list(qs)[0]
```

Note that you only get there if the queryset has not been iterated yet - else it would fetch the instance from it's resultcache, and then you'd get the same instance twice.

FWIW, the point of this code is to optimize db access (by not fetching the whole dataset when a single instance is asked for), and yes this behaviour is quite suprising to say the least.

If what you want is to keep the modify the first item while still keeping it as part of the dataset AND you're going to use the whole dataset, the simplest solution is to make a `list` from your queryset before:

```
obj = list(ModelA.objects.filter(flag=True))
obj1 = obj[0]
obj1.flag = False
obj1.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the first object does not match anymore the filtered queryset, you can't find it in the `obj` pointer. If you want to clone the queryset to another variable you can use [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Comment: Your answer is not enough. If you iterate over the queryset before modifiying one of it's items, you don't have this behaviour...